# nodejs and mqtt sending message either once or constantly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I am using NodeJS with the express and mqtt packages. 
Whenever the user pushes the button with the value 'test' a MQTT message should be sent.

However, whenever I send the mqtt message it is send either once when I use 'client.end()' or it keeps on sending the message constantly. I can´t send it twice when I push the button again

I use following code:

```
  module.exports = 
 {

 Send

 };


  function Send(User){

  client.on('connect', function() {

  client.publish('alarm/reset', 'Hallo' + Test);

  client.end(); 
   });


 }
```

In the '\' following code is used

```
router.post('/', Authencitation, function(req,res){
var test = req.body.test;

if (test == 'test')
{   

reset.Send(req.session.user);
console.log('inside reset');

}

res.redirect('/');

});
```

However, I alway get inside the function inside reset whenever the button is clicked. It seems it is a mistake made in the function Send(User) but I cannot spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution worked for me:

```
function Send(Test){

var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var client  = mqtt.connect()

client.on('connect', function() {

client.publish('Test', 'Hallo' + username);


client.end();   
    });

}
```